# Native C++ console screen buffer

Tags: c++, text-based

I'm trying to display a game in the console window using a screen buffer but cannot compile it.

I have this simple code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main() {
  const int width = 120, height = 40;

  wchar_t* screen = new wchar_t[width * height];
  HANDLE console = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
  SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(console);
  DWORD bytesWritten = 0;

  while (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++) screen[i] = L' ';
    wsprintf(&screen[width + 5], L"Testing");

    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(console, screen, width * height, {0, 0}, &bytesWritten);
    Sleep(1000 / 30);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It won't compile, getting two errors:

> test.cpp:16:44: error: cannot convert 'wchar_t*' to 'LPSTR {aka char*}' for argument '1' to 'int wsprintfA(LPSTR, LPCSTR, ...)'

and

> test.cpp:18:87: error: cannot convert 'wchar_t*' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' for argument '2' to 'BOOL WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA(HANDLE, LPCSTR, DWORD, COORD, PDWORD)'

How can I get this working and how to do it even better?

I'm using g++ 6.3.0 to compile.

Thanks!

Comment: The error messages are saying `wsprintf()` and `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA()` take `char*` not `wchar_t*` arguments. What happens when you change the type of `screen` to `char*` (and change the call to `new` to use `char`)?

Comment: Also changed WriteConsoleOutputCharacter() to WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA() and now it compiles. But VS Code outputs two error messages:
`argument of type "char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPWSTR" (15, 14)`
and
`argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR" (15, 34)` for wsprintf()

Comment: For what it's worth, the [docs for `wsprintfA()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-wsprintfa) say not to use it. In any event, you need to make your `screen` variable be the same type as the parameter of the function you're calling. If it takes a `wchar_t*`, then `screen` should be `wchar_t*`. If the function takes a `char*` then `screen` should be a `char*`.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. Just made myself a helper function: https://pastebin.com/LstCWUBt and it works perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @Kerdo if you've solved your problem, feel free to post it as an answer. This will make it more searchable, so other users with similar problems can learn from your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter()` to `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA()`, ditched `wsprintf()`, changed `screen[]` type from `wchar_t*` to `char*` and made my own helper function for displaying on the screen and now it works perfectly!

```
void toScreen(char*& screen, const int index, const char* text) {
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
    screen[index + i] = text[i];
}
```

Comment: Reasonable. There's nothing inherently wrong with `wchar_t`, and it's often better, but you need to use the `*W` functions instead of `*A` functions. Newer Windows functions (after Windows ME, so 21st century) often do not have *A variants.

Comment: @MSalters there are a lot of things inherently wrong with `wchar_t`, but on Windows it is still your best bet indeed :p

Comment: "strlen(text)" should be placed outside of the loop, otherwise the length will be calculated at EACH iteration, neither automatic compiler optimization helps.